# Iterate Key values in Batch

Tags: batch-file

Trying to iterate through two tables to map a machine to a username and change the reg key

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set host=machine1 machine2
set usernum=1

for %%i in (%host%) do (
    set /a usernum+=1
    if %COMPUTERNAME%==%%i ( set uname=user!usernum! )
)

if defined uname reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\xx\xx\" /t REG_SZ /v User /d %uname% /f
```

Previously tried, and would work for precious push where machines iterate, no rolling out to specific machines with specific names

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set host=machine1 machine2
set user=user1 user3
set usernum=1

for %%i in (%host%) do (
    set /a usernum+=1
    if %COMPUTERNAME%==%%i ( set uname=user!usernum! )
)

if defined uname reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\xx\xx\" /t REG_SZ /v User /d %uname% /f
```

Cannot get it to go through first mapping machine1 to user1 machine2 to user3 etc any advice? As mentioned this was fine when it was machine1 user1 machine2 user2 just added the machines in the right sequence for number. Or is there any easier way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set host=machine1 machine2
set user=user1 user3

for %%i in (%host%) do (
   if %COMPUTERNAME%==%%i ( for /F %%j in ("!user!") do set uname=%%j )
   for /F "tokens=1*" %%j in ("!user!") do set user=%%k
)

if defined uname reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\xx\xx\" /t REG_SZ /v User /d %uname% /f
```

Every time that a host is processed, a user is removed from its list. In this way, both values are keep synchronized...

*Another simpler method:*

```
@echo off

for %%i in ("machine1=user1" "machine2=user3") do (
   for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%j in ("%%~i") do (
      if %COMPUTERNAME%==%%j set uname=%%k
   )
)
```

Comment: That simpler did the job for me thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET "computername=machine3"

SET "uname="
FOR %%a IN (

user1 machine1
user2 machine3

) DO (
 IF DEFINED uname (
  if %COMPUTERNAME%==%%a ECHO reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\xx\xx\" /t REG_SZ /v User /d !uname! /f
  SET "uname="
 ) ELSE (SET "uname=%%a")
)


GOTO :EOF
```

How about this way> To me it manages the mapping in a more logical manner.

Obviously, the `reg` command is simply `echo`ed and the hostname is forced for testing purposes.